# Garmin GPX file, what units are the time values in?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, time, gpx, garmin

I have a GPX file from a Garmin GPSMap 62s. The GPX file has a time column but the values are in the following format:

42079.98593

This point was collected at around 14:20 on 7/8/2015.

I need to convert the time to Pacific Standard Time so I can join the point locations with some other data.  If I convert the GPX file to feature class using ArcGIS 10.3 the time gets converted to 2015-03-15T 23:39:44Z.  Is that Zulu time on the wrong date?

Comment: It should be GPS time, UTC from 00:00 Sunday. You not need to know the date the record was stored on to get the time right, just take off 86400 interactively until the result is less than 86400. To convert to PST take off 7 or 8 hours https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone. Beware the GPS week rollover at midnight Saturday. (4-5 pm Saturday PST)

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

> It should be GPS time, UTC from 00:00 Sunday. You not need to know the
>   date the record was stored on to get the time right, just take off
>   86400 interactively until the result is less than 86400. To convert to
>   PST take off 7 or 8 hours
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone. Beware the GPS week
>   rollover at midnight Saturday. (4-5 pm Saturday PST)

Comment: What about leap seconds?